# Como usar código vb.net y c# en la misma web application?

Tags: web, aplicación-web

tengo una webapplicattion, construida en vs 2017, en la cual quiero compilar código vb.net y c#.

Mi problema es que tengo una clase escrita en vb.net que necesito reutilizar  en un Page_Load escrito en c#.

Como puedo lograr esto ?

**EDITO:**
Gracias  Julio Moreno Dev por tu respuesta.

Antes de intentar esto con una webapplication lo intente con un sitio web, note que si era posible pero obtuve otro tipo de error relacionado con la con seccion compilers de mi web.config. El error es el siguiente:

"The CodeDom provider type "Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" could not be located."

Cual sera una mejor solución a mi problema:

1. Compilar mis clases vb.net com dll ?
2. Intentar resolver este error de compiladores ?

Comment: Buen día @Emerson Rios, si se puede hacer pero lo que debes de hacer es a través de una DLL, es decir debes pasar a DLL es la clase que tienes en vb.net y mandar a llamar esa DLL desde tu proyecto que esta en C#.

Comment: Ríos te dejo una liga donde se hable del tema así como te indicaba en el anterior comentario [https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/244b6ff8-4ad6-4fd0-acd1-e1250aafed3e/utilizar-una-clase-c-desde-mi-proyecto-vb?forum=vbes]

Comment: Entiendo, gracias. Intentare generar la dll de mis clases vb.net. Ahora bien, entiendo que esto es mas sencillo si lo hago en un sitio web...  voy a ampliar la pregunta para exponer mas del caso.